# Setting number of threads for xz on webmin filesystem backup module

Tags: linux, backup, webmin

Is it possible to change the number of threads for the xz command in the filesystem backup module? I would like to use all of the available cpu's on my system. I have tried to add --threads=0 in the Extra command-line parameters but it does not work giving error.

The error is:

`tar: unrecognized option '--threads=0'
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.`

So it seems the options are passed to tar and not xz.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `XZ_DEFAULTS` environment variable. For example, put this in your system-wide `/etc/profile`:

```
export XZ_DEFAULTS='--threads=0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Parallel compression will not get to the theoretical maximum throughput for a number of reasons. Most obvious of which, only recently has the man page admitted that `xz --threads`  has been implemented.

---

With only options to GNU tar, you can provide your own compression wrapper:   `--use-compress-program=/usr/local/bin/xz-thread.sh`

Where xz-thread.sh is a thin wrapper script that passes all the arguments it gets and adds some more:

```
#!/bin/sh
xz --threads=0 "$@"
```

In a similar way, you can substitute `xz` with other compress programs with gzip-like syntax, like `zstd`.

Comment: Thanks. Although now it is throwing error `tar: Cannot use multi-volume compressed archives.` I have disabled the webmin compression and added this as an extra command line parameter

Comment: I was actually thinking of using pigz as a replacement for gzip which uses parallel compression.

Comment: Good thing you tested. You may need to write your own backup and compress script beyond  options to tar to accomplish what you want.